# Tapestry - Loop through two lists

Tags: java, tapestry

Is there any way to iterate through two lists simultaneously? Loop component works great but I think it only can contain a list.

```
<t:loop source="Rooms" values="rooms">
```

I would like to add another list to that Loop.

Comment: you mean nested for loops?

Comment: I simply need to list in tml two lists at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Java

```
@Property Room room;
@Property Bed bed;
```

TML

```
<t:loop source="rooms" value="room">
    <t:loop source="room.beds" value="bed">
    ${room.name} ${bed.name}
   ...
```